# XSLT compilation failure with camel-saxon

Tags: apache-camel, xslt-2.0, saxon, jbossfuse, apache-servicemix

I am using Fuse 6.1 and camel 2.12 version for my project and facing following problem. I am trying to pass java.util.HashMap to my xslt and accessing map to retrieve bunch of values in my XSLT. For this i am constructing a map and placing it the in header in a bean and accessing it XSLT. I created a test case to run this route and everything is working fine, able to access  map in XSLT, XSLT is compiling fine and generating expected XML if i had net.sf.saxon/saxon/8.9.0.4 in my class path but if i try to deploy same route in fuse 6.1 which has camel-saxon feature, its failing with following error. Later i realized and replaced net.sf.saxon jar file with camel-saxon dependency in pom file and test case for the same route is failing. Question is how can i make it run using camel-saxon feature.

Here is my route

```
<route id="newCustomerMapToXmlTransformationRoute">
            <from uri="direct:newCustomerMapToXmlTransformation" />
            <to uri="customerIdGenerationProcessor" /> 
            <to uri="xslt:xslt/flatFileToCustomer.xsl?transformerFactory=tFactory&amp;failOnNullBody=false" />
            <removeHeader headerName="customerProfileMap" />
        </route>

XSLT: 
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
    xmlns:Map="java.util.HashMap"  exclude-result-prefixes="Map" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0">

<xsl:variable name="sourceName" select="Map:get($customerProfileMap,'aaaa')"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Getting following error: 
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197) 
[                          main] XsltErrorListener              ERROR Cannot find a matching 2-argument function named {java.util.HashMap}get(). Note that direct calls to Java methods are not available under Saxon-HE; 
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Cannot find a matching 2-argument function named {java.util.HashMap}get(). Note that direct calls to Java methods are not available under Saxon-HE
```

I spent lot of time to find a solution and could not find any. Can any one help me solve this issue? Does it make sense to uninstall camel-saxon feature from fuse and use  net.sf.saxon jar?

Answer (score 2):

From Saxon 9.2 (released in August 2009) the product was repackaged; the free version Saxon-HE does not support calls to Java extension functions (hence the error message which fully explains what is going on). The last open-source version to support this feature was Saxon-B 9.1, which of course you are welcome to continue using if you wish.

The reasons for the repackaging were primarily commercial: we felt that we could only continue to invest in development of the open source version if we could get a larger proportion of the user base to move over to paid versions, and this strategy proved successful, which is why the open source version continues to be developed today.

Comment: Thank you Michael. Seems like we cannot use older versions. Will pass individual fields as params to XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

Fuse 6.1 comes with Saxon-HE (9.5.1.2_1) which is a free library that has a limited support for XSTL.

You can read about the other versions of Saxon which you need to pay $$$ to get at: http://saxon.sourceforge.net/

The older version of Saxon 8.9, may have more functionality, which they removed in 9.x and only offer in the paid $$$ versions.

You can instead likely set those headers in the Camel message first, and then access those from the xslt file, as documented here, at the section *Getting Parameters into the XSLT to work with*

- http://camel.apache.org/xslt

Comment: I suggest your comment "has a limited support for XSTL" is to broad. HE provides all the features defined in the XSLT W3C standard except schema-aware processing (source: http://saxon.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thank you Ibsen for the quick response.Can we use 8.9 version  instead of camel-saxon feature?Do you see any problem here?